# Rolling upgrade for Cassandra 1.0.9 cluster to 1.2.1

Tags: cassandra

As part of a production problem we have, we want to upgrade our production 1.0.9 cluster to 1.2.1/2.

While testing the upgrade in our dev environment, I'm getting the following exceptions while doing a simple list operation using cli on one of the upgraded cluster nodes: (Just one node out of 3 is upgraded)

```
[default@testKS] list testCF;
Using default limit of 100
Using default column limit of 100
null
TimedOutException()
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result.read(Cassandra.java:12932)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:734)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:718)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeList(CliClient.java:1485)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:272)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:210)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:337)
```

I get the same exception running the same list operation on a non-upgraded node (1.0.9):

```
[default@testKS] list testCF;
Using default limit of 100
null
TimedOutException()
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result.read(Cassandra.java:12830)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:762)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:734)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeList(CliClient.java:1390)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:269)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:220)
at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:348)
```

When trying the same list operation on another 1.0.9 node I get no errors, I assume this node holds the only replica:

```
[default@testKS] list testCF;
Using default limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 0a
=> (column=0a, value=0a, timestamp=1362642828623000)

1 Row Returned.
Elapsed time: 11 msec(s).
```

The testCF I'm using has just one key and value and the timeout exception
is consistent.
I'm using replication factor of 1, but all three nodes seems to be up and
synced.

It seems like it's the simplest upgrade one can make from 1.0.9 from
1.2.1/2 and it's still failing to use range(?) scans.
The same error occurs when using select * queries from cql client.
I didn't do any special test so I'm guessing this problem should occur in
any upgrade from 1.0.9 and it will be quite easy to reproduce.

nodetool ring shows all nodes are up (running on all nodes):

```
-bash-4.1$ nodetool -h localhost ring

Datacenter: US
==========
Replicas: 1

Address Rack Status State Load Owns Token
113427455640312821154458202477256070485
33.33.33.2 RAC1 Up Normal 39.31 KB 33.33% 0
33.33.33.3 RAC1 Up Normal 63.39 KB 33.33% 56713727820156410577229101238628035242
33.33.33.4 RAC1 Up Normal 63.39 KB 33.33% 113427455640312821154458202477256070485
```

Once I finish the upgrade on all nodes, the cluster goes back to normal.

Why is that?
It should not be that way? Right?
As my understanding, Cassandra should be able to support a rolling upgrade such as this, Right?
If anyone encountered this problem, or thinks he knows what the problem might be,
Please advise,
Or.

Comment: Do you get errors in the cassandra logs?  Usually a consistent timeout exception means there is an exception.  Often the logs are in /var/log/cassandra/system.log.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling upgrades are possible, and I do them all the time.  You should probably not jump 2 major releases 1.0 - 1.2.  I know its classified as a point release, but a lot changed.

You should do a rolling upgrade to 1.1.X, then run upgradesstables on all nodes, then repair on all nodes.

Then rolling upgrade to 1.2.X, then run upgradesstables on all nodes, then repair on all nodes.

So, rolling update is supported, but you should do it in a rational fashion to reduce risk.  Your 3 nodes cluster shouldn't take long at all.